Column "size" cannot be 'null' Use DBNull instead
I have a problem with the following code (derived from https://github.com/KlausThorax/sourcelauncher/blob/main/Forms1.c):
public void ReadXML()
{
    if (!File.Exists("files.xml")) { return; } //if not exist return
    creatTable();

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("files.xml"))
    {
        reader.ReadToFollowing("critical");
        DataRow Row;

        do
        {
            Row = downloads_info.NewRow();

            reader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
            Row["path"] = reader.GetAttribute("path");
            Row["hash"] = reader.GetAttribute("hash");
            var size = reader.GetAttribute("size"); // get the data value
            if (size == null)
            {
                // if no value, then replace with the SQL required null value
                size = DBNull.Value;
            }
            Row["size"] = size;

            downloads_info.Rows.Add(Row);
        } while (reader.ReadToFollowing("critical"));
    }


    calc_downloads();
}

And now I get this:

[SecuritySafeCritical] protected virtual object
DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) {    RuntimeMethodInfo
runtimeMethodInfo =
(RuntimeMethodInfo)RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(methodHandle: new
RuntimeMethodHandleInternal(GetInvokeMethod()), reflectedType:
(RuntimeType)GetType());  return runtimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(this,
BindingFlags.Default, null, args, null); }

from Delegate.cs
The Sourcecode represents a Gamepatcher/Gamelauncher von Cabal Online.
I´m very new with C# Programming and I try to understand the Code...

You need to do what the message says. But first you need to change your calls to GetAttribute so you check the return values each time. Do not assume that the data you are reading will always be correct.

Yea, but where i must it change? I´m really new at C# and need it only for a simple Gamepatcher.

Try Row["size"] = reader.GetAttribute("size") ?? DBNull.Value. For the background on what DBNull is and why it exists the remarks in the documenation might give you some insights.

I got now this Error:
Fehler CS0019 Der ??-Operator kann nicht auf Operanden vom Typ "string" und "DBNull" angewendet werden

Forgot about the type differences here. Then you need todo a classic if else like in the answer to this question

This is not optimised code, but it should make it clear what you need to do to protect yourself from errors like this:
var path = reader.GetAttribute("path"); // get the data value
if (path == null)
{
    // if no value, then replace with the SQL required null value
    path = DBNull.Value;
}
Row["path"] = path; // add this value to the row

And do the same for the other values.

Can i show you the whole Project?

@Frank I'm afraid that's beyond the scope of what we do here. Any questions should be limited to specifics and ideally reduced to a [mvce] to focus the answers.

Okay. I have a Source for a Gamepatcher for Cabal Online. I want to compile it, but there i get that Error above. I´ve tried your Solutions, but i think i messed up all. That´s why i ask. It´s not really big, the most Action are in 1 File i think.

We cannot guess what errors you are now seeing. Please edit your question and update it with the details of what you have tried, and what error messages it creates. NOTE: do not post the entire project, just the part that is the currecnt problem.

Just changed now the Question with the Edit from you. But the Error is the same...

Without analysing the entire source file that you are working with it is impossible to guess why that error occurs. i suggest you contact the person who wrote that code.

This is a Problem, the Creator from the Source Code didn´t work on that anymore

I suggest you forget about this. I had a look and it's nearly 500 lines of C#, which includes database access. Unless you have good experience of both subjects then what you are trying to do is probably a waste of time.
